# Editing the gravityforms form tag?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, html

I need my gravityforms form tag to have an "oninput" in it.

Like so:

```
<form oninput="loanval.value=parseInt(loan.value, 10).toLocaleString('en-US').replace(',', ' ');">
```

I read about the gravity forms hooks, but there not really a lot of documentation and I'm not very experienced with coding. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `gform_form_tag`-filter. It is documented over here: https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_form_tag/. For your example it would look something like this:

```
add_filter( 'gform_form_tag', 'form_tag', 10, 2 );
function form_tag( $form_tag, $form ) {
    if ( $form['id'] != 3 ) { //Select the form by ID
        return $form_tag;
    }
        $form_tag = str_ireplace( "<form", "<form oninput=\"loanval.value=parseInt(loan.value, 10).toLocaleString('en-US').replace(',', ' ');\"", $form_tag );
        return $form_tag;
}
```

But you could also use jQuery to do your Javascript on change, which is more simple and accomplishes the same effect as your `oninput`-attribute:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // "gform_1" Target the form by id
    $('#gform_1 input, #gform_1 textarea').on('change', function() {
        // Do your "oninput" code
    }
});
```

Change the ID's to target the desired form. For example if your form has ID 20, then change it  to `#gform_20`.

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery is available and either the form ID is static or you have access to it in your JS, I would go with BasC's jQuery approach.

Otherwise, here's a super simple plugin that will allow you to put the event attribute (any event attribute) on the <form> tag itself.

http://gravitywiz.com/gravity-forms-tag-editor/

Example usage:

```
new GW_Tag_Editor( array(
    'tag'          => 'form',
    'form_id'      => 123,
    'oninput'      => 'loanval.value=parseInt(loan.value, 10).toLocaleString('en-US').replace(',', ' ');'
) );
```